# Grails: Custom validator based on a previous value of the field

Tags: grails, custom-validators

I am trying to create a custom validator for variable 'amount' in my domain class, such that the new value should be greater than previous by 0.50.

For example, lets say the previous value was 1.0, next time the value should be atleast: [previous value + 0.50] or more.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 4):

You can try reading `domainEntity.getPersistentValue('amount')`.

**EDIT:** ... in custom validator, like:

```
class Bid { 
  Double amount 
  ...
  static constraints = { amount(validator: { double a, Bid b -> 
    def oldValue = b.getPersistentValue('amount')
    a > oldValue + 0.5 ? true : "Amount $a should be at least ${oldValue  + 0.5}" }) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I add this to my constraint for amount in the domain class.

Comment: I believe yes, it's a valid Grails code, and you do have an entity instance in validator.

Comment: `code`
class Bid {
 double amount
 Date dateTimeOfBid
 Customer bidder
 
 static belongsTo = [listing:Listing]
 
 static constraints = {
     amount(validator: {Bid.getPersistentValue('amount')})
     dateTimeOfBid(nullable:false)
     bidder(nullable:false)
 }
}

Comment: That  markdown for some reason is not working for me. I am still kind of confused and new to this grails. Can you take a look at it and give any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thx Victor Sergienko, but I do a little modification on your code

```
class Bid { 
  Double amount 
  ...
  static constraints = { amount(validator: { double a, Bid b -> 
    Bid tempBid = Bid.get(b.id)
    def oldValue = tempBid.getPersistentValue('amount')
    a > oldValue + 0.5 ? true : "Amount $a should be at least ${oldValue  + 0.5}" }) 
  }
}
```

The difference is at this line :

```
Bid tempBid = Bid.get(b.id)
def oldValue = tempBid.getPersistentValue('amount')
```

I don't why `b.getPersistentValue('amount')` is always return null value, my grails version is 2.4.3