# How can I declare inList constraints from a controller in Grails?

Tags: grails, controller, constraints

Can anyone show me how to declare an `inList` constraint within a Grails controller?

Let’s say I have this class:

```
class A {
    List hello
}
```

How can I add the `inList` constraint for the `hello` `List` from within the controller?

Answer (score 2):

Define a constraint in which a `List` property has values validated against a list of lists? Sounds weird. But you can do it. With this class:

```
class A {
    List hello
    static constraint = {
        hello inList:[['abc','def','ghi'],[1,2,3],['a','b']]
    }
}
```

you can do this in your controller:

```
def instance1 = new A(hello:['abc','def','ghi']).save()    //valid
def instance2 = new A(hello:[1,2,3]).save()                //valid
def instance3 = new A(hello:['a','b']).save()              //valid
def instance4 = new A(hello:['a','b','c']).save()    //invalid
def instance5 = new A(hello:[1,2]).save()            //invalid
```

If `A` is a domain class whose instances are persisted in a traditional database, however, the `hello` property would be dropped, so you’d need to define it using

```
static hasMany = [hello: SomeClass]
```

instead.

Comment: I need it to be done dynamically.I am fetching the data from the web service and I have to add it in the hello list( the value which i have fetched)

Comment: No, you can't do it in class definition. You can define a domain class to maintain the valid options, and check the input values against it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom validator to your fields that check if data are in List. You will have to implement the in list checking manually.
You can find [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) the official documentation. There are some stackoverflow entries that can help you like

[Grails: Custom validator based on a previous value of the field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005932/grails-custom-validators)