# How to establish domain class constraints on a hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a user class as a grails domain class. I would like to establish constraints for a String list that is declared in a `hasMany` relationship.

```
class User {
    String name

    static hasMany = [interests: String]
}
```

How could I specify an `inList` constraint for each interest?

Comment: What has been tried yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272680/how-can-i-declare-inlist-constraints-from-a-controller-in-grails

Answer (score 1):

you could use an Enum instead, so your inList Constraint will be handled automatically?

The solution could look like this:

```
class User {
  String name

  static hasMany = [interests: Interest]
}

Enum Interest {
  FOO('foo'),
  BAR('bar')

  final String id

  Interest(String id) { this.id = id }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How could I get the list of possible interests as String?