# How can I validate a Grails domain class field based on its previous value?

Tags: validation, grails

First off: As far as I can tell, this is not a duplicate. The question [“Grails: Custom validator based on a previous value of the field”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005932/grails-custom-validator-based-on-a-previous-value-of-the-field) got [an answer suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5006108/758011) the method `getPersistentValue()`.

I am using Grails 2.2.3. The context is a “current password” field, where a user enters his current password before being allowed to change it to a new one.

So I have tried *using* `getPersistentValue()`, by means of something like this as a [custom validator](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Constraints/validator.html):

```
previousPassword(validator: { val, obj ->
    def previous = obj.getPersistentValue('password')
    if(val != previous) {
        return ['yoErrorCode']
    }
})
```

When I now try to update the user’s password in a controller action:

```
def changePassword() {
    User user = User.get(springSecurityService?.currentUser?.id)

    user.validate(["previousPassword"])

    user.password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(params.updatedPassword)

    if (user.errors.allErrors.size() == 0) {
        try {
            user.save(failOnError: true)
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            flash.message = "An error occurred"
            render(view: "password_change", model: [user: user])
            return
        }
        flash.message = "Updated password"
        render(view: "password_change", model: [user: user])
        return
    } else {
        render(view: "password_change", model: [user: user])
        return
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Am I doing this wrong (the correct answer is probably “Yes”)? Or is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: Which version of Grails?

Comment: @dmahapatro 2.2.3. I’ll update the question.

Comment: looks like the object you passed is not an instance of the class it meant to be ?

Comment: Can you also add the implementation where the update is performed?

Comment: @johnSmith I think it’s of the right class. I have other validators on the class using this same pattern — where the `obj` is a user object and the `val` is the particular field on which I’m using the validator — and they’re working fine.

Comment: How is `previousPassword` captured from end user input? Shouldn't that be part of `params` and set to user before validate? Secondly, `springSecurityService?.currentUser` should give the `User` domain of the current logged in user, why is it fetched again using `get()`? I do not see anything else going wrong apart from the above  questions.

Comment: `previousPassword` is indeed part of `params`. It probably should be set to the user beforehand, yes. The line using `get` in the code actually uses `findBy` on another field — why, I’m not sure (I didn’t write that part). :)